# How to use Twig to pull drop down menu items for a front end form

Tags: templating

I have this code that will pull the values of a checkbox or radio from the fields in Craft CMS, do be used and selected by a user on a front end form.

```
<ul>
    {% for checkboxOption in currentUser.fieldHandle.options %}
        {% set checked = false %}

        {% if checkboxOption.selected %}
            {% set checked = true %}
        {% endif %}

        <li>
            <input type="radio" value="{{ checkboxOption.value }}" name="fields[fieldHandle]" {% if checked %} checked="checked" {% endif %}><span>{{ checkboxOption.label }}</span>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

How do I do the same for a dropdown list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd do something very similar:

```
<select name="fields[fieldHandle]">

    {% for dropdownOption in currentUser.fieldHandle.options %}
        <option value="{{ dropdownOption.value }}"{% if option.selected %} selected{% endif %}>{{ dropdownOption.label }}</option>
    {% endfor %}

</select>
```

Comment: Brad, thanks for your help. This worked, and encouraging to know I wasn't far off when I had!